# How to Change the color of the text present in table view from its default black color in an iphone application?

Tags: iphone

How to Change the color of the text present in table view from its default black color in an iphone application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil) 
 {
 cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
 cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor]; //Change the text color

 }

 // Configure the cell...

 return cell;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
```

You can also give RGB values like

```
cell.textLabel.textColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:200/256.0 green:0/256.0 blue:67/256.0 alpha:1.0];
```

All the best.